# How to express the "Bias for action" concept

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

I was wondering how could someone express the idea of "Bias for action", especially in the sense of it being a specific *character trait* for someone.

Here is a succinct description of what I mean with "Bias for action" from [defmacro.org](http://www.defmacro.org/2016/12/22/models.html):

> - **Bias for action** – in daily life many important decisions are easily reversible. It's not enough to have information – it's crucial to move quickly and recover if you were wrong, than to deliberately indefinitely.
>
>   **Idiom:** One test is worth a thousand expert opinions.
>     **Idiom:** The best thing you can do is the right thing, the next best thing is the wrong thing, and the worst thing you can do is nothing.
>     **Note:** The best people do this naturally, without brooding, and with a light touch.

My Calligraphy teacher (who is Japanese) suggested "即決即断" (which is close enough, and has also the nice benefit of being expressed using Kanji alone, which is a plus for me) but I wonder if there is any alternative that may be even more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

即断即決 is probably not wrong, but I think the following proverbs/idioms/catchphrases directly describe this concept (unfortunately none is kanji-only):

- [案ずるより産むが易し](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%A1%88%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E7%94%A3%E3%82%80%E3%81%8C%E6%98%93%E3%81%97)
  (literally) It's easier to bear a child than to worry about it.
- やればわかる
  If you do it, you understand it.
- やってから悩め / やってから考えろ / 考える前に(まず)行動せよ
  Worry/Think after doing it.; Act before thinking.
- 頭より手を動かせ

To describe someone's trait, you can say 即断即決型の人, 考える前に行動する人, 実践派の人, etc. 行動派の人 should work too when it's contrasted with 慎重派の人/理論派の人.

Comment: 考える前に行動する人 strikes me as being negative compared to the other ones... or is it neutral?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Yes it can be negative, but not necessarily so. 何も考えずに行動する人 would be clearly negative :)